# Using :| in functional code -- recursion on sets

Tags: dafny

How might one recurse over a set, S, in Dafny when writing pure functional code? I can use :| in imperative code, having checked for non-emptiness, to select an element, s, then recurse on S - {s}. Not quite sure how to make :| deterministic and use it in functional code.

Answer (score 0):

Good question! (I wish downvoters would have the courage to leave a comment...)

This is addressed in depth in Rustan's paper ["Compiling Hilbert's Epsilon Operator"](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/krml252.pdf).

In particular, see section 3.2, which describes how to write a deterministic function by recursion over sets. For reasons not entirely clear to me, the paper's Dafny code proving lemma `ThereIsASmallest` doesn't work for me in modern Dafny. Here is a version that works (but is ugly):

```
lemma ThereIsASmallest(S: set<int>)
    requires S != {}
    ensures exists x :: x in S && forall y | y in S :: x <= y
{
    var y :| y in S;
    if S != {y} {
        var S' := S - {y};
        assert forall z | z in S :: z in S' || z == y;
        ThereIsASmallest(S');
        var x' :| x' in S' && forall y | y in S' :: x' <= y;
        var x := min2(y, x');
        assert x in S;
    }
}
```

Finally, as an aside, note that the technique of section 3.2 relies on having a total order on the type. If you are trying to do something fully polymorphic, then as far as I know it isn't possible.